# Extracing filenames from a string of HTML with Python 2.7

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am parsing an HTML document with `BeautifulSoup`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
page = requests.get("http://www.crmpicco.co.uk/?page_id=82&lottoId=27")

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
entry_content = soup.find_all('div', class_='entry-content')

print(entry_content[1])
```

which gives me this string:

```
<div class="entry-content"><span class="red">Week 27: </span><br/><br/>Saturday 1st February 2020<br/>(in red)<br/><br/> <img height="50" src="http://www.crmpicco.co.uk/wp-content/themes/2010/images/lotto_balls/17.gif" vspace="12" width="70"/> <img height="50" src="http://www.crmpicco.co.uk/wp-content/themes/2010/images/balls/21.gif" vspace="12" width="70"/> <img height="50" src="http://www.crmpicco.co.uk/wp-content/themes/2010/images/balls/31.gif" vspace="12" width="70"/> <img height="50" src="http://www.crmpicco.co.uk/wp-content/themes/2010/images/balls/47.gif" vspace="12" width="70"/> <img height="50" src="http://www.crmpicco.co.uk/wp-content/themes/lotto2010/images/balls/bonus43.gif" vspace="12" width="70"/><br/><br/>Wednesday 5th February 2020<br/><br/><strong><span class="red">RESULTS NOT AVAILABLE</span></strong><br/><br/><br/><br/><a href="?page_id=82">Click here</a> to see other results.<br/> </div>
```

I would like to get filenames of each of the gif paths in the string and I (think) the `findall` method in the regular expression module is the way to do it, but i'm not having much success.

What is the optimal way to do this? Can it be done in one call with BeautifulSoup?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM Ideally, i'd have an array of filenames (12, 56, 18, 72, 16 etc). I was trying to stick the full path `re.findall(r'src="(.*)/>', entry_content[1])` and then work from there. Disclaimer: Python nubz0r. ;)

Comment: There's no divs with entry-content on the url you've provided, are you sure it is the correct one?

Comment: @isopach No, you're right. I changed the URL, but there are divs with a class of `entry-content`. You can see in the string example above that the div has the class of `entry-content`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of regex I would recommend to use `HTMLParser` class ([`python2`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html)/[`python3`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html)) from the standard library. It has a [`handle_starttag`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html#html.parser.HTMLParser.handle_starttag) method which called to handle the start of a tag.

```
>>> source = "\n".join(entry_content) # I assume "entry_content" is a list of div elements.
>>>
>>> try:
...     from HTMLParser import HTMLParser # python 2
... except ImportError:
...     from html.parser import HTMLParser
...
>>> class SrcParser(HTMLParser):
...     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
...         self.links = []
...         self._basename = kwargs.pop('only_basename', False)
...         super(SrcParser, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
...
...     def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
...         for attr, val in attrs:
...             if attr == 'src' and val.endswith("gif"):
...                 if self._basename:
...                     import os.path
...                     val = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(val))[0]
...                 self.links.append(val)
...
>>> source_parser = SrcParser()
>>> source_parser.feed(source)
>>> print(*source_parser.links, sep='\n')
http://www.crmpicco.co.uk/wp-content/themes/2010/images/lotto_balls/17.gif
http://www.crmpicco.co.uk/wp-content/themes/2010/images/balls/21.gif
http://www.crmpicco.co.uk/wp-content/themes/2010/images/balls/31.gif
http://www.crmpicco.co.uk/wp-content/themes/2010/images/balls/47.gif
http://www.crmpicco.co.uk/wp-content/themes/lotto2010/images/balls/bonus43.gif
>>>
>>> source_parser = SrcParser(only_basename=True)
>>> source_parser.feed(source)
>>> print(*source_parser.links, sep='\n')
17
21
31
47
bonus43
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any divs with `entry-content` on your page, but this should work. Change the `col-md-4` to `entry-content`.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re


page = requests.get("http://www.crmpicco.co.uk/?page_id=82&lottoId=27")

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

for entry_content in soup.find_all('div',class_='col-md-4'):
    print(entry_content.img['src'].rsplit('/', 1)[-1].split('.')[0])
```

```
zce
691505
gaiq
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend another solution that is compatible with both Python 2 and python 3 and is ideal for extracting data from XML.

```
from simplified_scrapy.simplified_doc import SimplifiedDoc
html = '''
<div class="entry-content"><span class="red">Week 27: </span><br/><br/>Saturday 1st February 2020<br/>(in red)<br/><br/> <img height="50" src="http://www.crmpicco.co.uk/wp-content/themes/2010/images/lotto_balls/17.gif" vspace="12" width="70"/> <img height="50" src="http://www.crmpicco.co.uk/wp-content/themes/2010/images/balls/21.gif" vspace="12" width="70"/> <img height="50" src="http://www.crmpicco.co.uk/wp-content/themes/2010/images/balls/31.gif" vspace="12" width="70"/> <img height="50" src="http://www.crmpicco.co.uk/wp-content/themes/2010/images/balls/47.gif" vspace="12" width="70"/> <img height="50" src="http://www.crmpicco.co.uk/wp-content/themes/lotto2010/images/balls/bonus43.gif" vspace="12" width="70"/><br/><br/>Wednesday 5th February 2020<br/><br/><strong><span class="red">RESULTS NOT AVAILABLE</span></strong><br/><br/><br/><br/><a href="?page_id=82">Click here</a> to see other results.<br/> </div>
'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
div = doc.select('div.entry-content')
srcs = div.selects('img>src()')
print (srcs)
print ([src.rsplit('/', 1)[-1].split('.')[0] for src in srcs])
```

Result:

```
['http://www.crmpicco.co.uk/wp-content/themes/2010/images/lotto_balls/17.gif', 'http://www.crmpicco.co.uk/wp-content/themes/2010/images/balls/21.gif', 'http://www.crmpicco.co.uk/wp-content/themes/2010/images/balls/31.gif', 'http://www.crmpicco.co.uk/wp-content/themes/2010/images/balls/47.gif', 'http://www.crmpicco.co.uk/wp-content/themes/lotto2010/images/balls/bonus43.gif']
['17', '21', '31', '47', 'bonus43']
```

Here are more examples:https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/blob/master/doc_examples/